# Yellow substance being consumed

Tags: plot-explanation, mother

In the film [*mother!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother!), Jennifer Lawrence's character is seen drinking some kind of yellow substance several times. She pours it from what looks like an old bottle into a glass of water, then drinks it.

What is it, and why does she drink it?

The bottle it's poured from and her drinking it can be seen briefly in this trailer.

Comment: It is never explained. Only speculation is available: https://www.bustle.com/p/what-is-the-yellow-powder-in-mother-what-jennifer-lawrence-drinks-is-as-mysterious-as-the-movie-itself-2346777

Comment: After watching the film, to me the "bottle" was a prescription bottle. I'm fairly sure it had a prescription label.

Comment: @user598527 Which doesn't answer my question of *what* was in the bottle.

Comment: I posted a comment, not an answer. I wanted to give more substance and hear the opinion of others about the look of this bottle.

Comment: https://www.romper.com/p/what-is-the-yellow-powder-in-mother-it-is-important-to-the-title-character-2356056

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to an [interview](http://www.indiewire.com/2017/09/mother-darren-aronofsky-explains-mythology-allegory-bible-jennifer-lawrence-1201877848/) Aronofsky did, he says the answer is a deliberate secret:

> And what is that yellow potion that Mother drinks when she gets
>   anxious? “I will never answer what Jen is drinking,” said Aronofsky.
>   “That secret I will take to the grave.”

The [most popular theory](https://www.thedailybeast.com/mother-review-jennifer-lawrence-goes-insane-in-the-most-wtf-movie-of-the-year) is that it was a reference to the 1892 story The Yellow Wallpaper. But that sounds too mild to be a secret Aronofsky takes to the grave.

Comment: Take the secret of something in a movie to the grave, that doesn't make sense to me.